# Remotely promote a Standard user to Administrator?

Tags: windows, permissions, remote-access

I have a user who took a laptop to work from home for a few months. It's just a small business, so we don't have a domain, just consumer-grade laptops with Windows 10 Home OEM (but that's a different issue). Each laptop has an Admin account, which has the same password on every laptop, and an account for the user. The problem is that we accidentally made this user a Standard user, so now she can't install any software. How do I remotely promote her to an Administrator user, without giving her the Admin password? I use TeamViewer for remote support, but if she launches TeamViewer, it will just have Standard user permissions, not elevated permissions, so I won't be able to elevate her permissions while connected through the un-elevated session.

There are some similar questions, but they appear to be for businesses using Active Directory, a domain, or Windows Professional. This is just an out-of-the-box laptop from Sams Club with a Standard user account and an Administrator account thrown on it. There's no VPN or anything, just a simple internet connection at her home office and at my office.

I would like to avoid Microsoft Remote Desktop because configuring her router firewall remotely is so difficult.

Comment: Once you are logged into a TeamViewer session you can escalate her permissions since you know the password to the Administrator account....

Comment: @Ramhound If Teamviewer isn't elevated, I can't see the UAC window, so I can't enter the admin password.

Comment: I routinely remote into a machine with a non-elevated user account, I always get a UAC promote, when I escalate the users permission

Comment: @Ramhound That's weird, I just tried it again with the full version of TeamViewer on the remote computer and the session code, and I could see the UAC prompt. Then I uninstalled the full version and connected with QuickSupport and now I can't see the UAC prompt. I will have to do some more testing.

Comment: @Ramhound From my testing, it looks like if TeamViewer has been installed by an administrator previously, the standard user can run it on the host and the remote client can see UAC prompts. But if the standard user installs TeamViewer, the remote client will not be able to see the UAC prompts.

Comment: You mentioned `QuickSupport` which isn't the full fledge Teamviwer client.  So are you doing the full version of TeamViewer or are you using QuickSupport?

Comment: @Ramhound Full version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44373/discussion-between-browly-and-ramhound).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution with TeamViewer QuickSupport. I happened to already have a commercial license for TeamViewer, but it is free for personal use.

1. Install [TeamViewer](http://ninite.com/teamviewer) (full version) on your computer if you don't have it.
2. Have the remote user download the [TeamViewer QuickSupport](https://download.teamviewer.com/download/TeamViewerQS_en.exe) installer.
3. Upon running the installer, the remote user will get a UAC prompt asking them for an administrator password, since they are a standard user. They should just click "No", and TeamViewer QuickSupport will run without elevated permissions.
4. Have the remote user provide their session code to you (not necessary if you have created a [custom QuickSuport module](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/custom-modules/?module=QuickSupport&os=Windows)).
5. Enter the session code on your side. In the Authentication window, instead of entering their password, click "Advanced" and choose Authentication: Windows, then enter the Admin username and password for the remote computer. (If using a custom QuickSupport module, instead of Remote Control > Prompt for Confirmation, choose Remote Control > Windows Authentication).
   [image: Screenshot of Teamviewer Authentication window with Authentication: Windows; Username: Admin]
6. The guest will see Teamviewer QS close and the UAC prompt reappear, but this time it will not prompt them for a password, so they can just click Yes.
7. (If using the Custom module, you may need to click "Prompt for Confirmation). You now have a remote control session with elevated permissions
8. Promote the user to an Administrator using your preferred method (I like [Windows Key]+X, A, Alt+Y, net localgroup Administrators "Susan Drew" /add [Enter])

Comment: Please upload images to Superuser instead of linking to images to private Google Drive accounts.  This insures images can always be accessed.